# How can potential energy increase?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy, work, potential-energy

If work is done on a body, the energy of the body increases. If work is done by the body, energy decreases. When we take a body up to some height, some work is done by us on the body, which is stored in the body and some work is done by gravity which is negative and so energy of body is lost.
As the two works are equal and opposite they add up to zero. Hence no work done means no energy transfer. So, why do we say potential energy of the system has increased? There is no increase in kinetic energy here.

Comment: Then net work is equal to the change in kinetic energy only. Not energy in general. So you have net work zero and zero kinetic energy

Comment: Potential energy is of a configuration, with respect to another configuration. An inert body like a weight can't have a potential energy by itself because it only has the one configuration. The potential energy belongs to the configuration of the system of masses (e.g. planet, weight).

Answer (score 3):

> When we take a body up to some height some work is done by us on the
> body, which is stored in the body

Potential energy is not stored in a body. Gravitational potential energy is stored in earth-body system. That's because all potential energy, not just gravitational potential energy, is a system property and not a property of a single body.

In effect, the negative work done by gravity on the body takes the energy you gave the body when you did positive work lifting it beginning at rest and bringing it to rest at a certain height and stores the energy as gravitational potential energy of the earth-body system.

> There is no increase in kinetic energy here.

The work energy theorem states that the net work done on a body equals its change in kinetic energy. Since the negative work done by gravity equals the positive work lifting the body the net work is zero and the change in KE is zero.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You are right that no *net* work is done.

But gravitational potential energy is not the net work. It is purely a measure of the stored energy that *gravity* can do work with. So all other work is ignored in that context.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to define your system, you implicitly defined it as the Earth and the object. Then you have to distinguish between conservative and non-conservative forces. First you applied a force that is *external* to the system and did non-conservative work and thus increased the total energy of the object. Then the gravity force (*internal to the system*) acts upon the object, which is a conservative force and then is conservative-work, meaning that the total energy remain the same in all the route that the object does. If the object returns again to the ground, at the instant of the impact you have again non-conservative work that removes the energy given at the beginning.

Often, internal forces are conservative and external non-conservative. But you could have non-conservative internal forces too, as happens in inelastic collisions (like the case I wrote in the past paragraph ;)).

Answer (score 1):

You've applied work energy theorem which states that:
\begin{gather} W=\Delta T \end{gather}

So (according to your though process) you apply an upward force equal to the downward force so the total work is equal to zero so there no change in Kinetic energy

But the work energy theorem don't apply here, indeed there will be no change in Kinetic energy but you've forgot that the potential energy has another way to be calculated with.

Since we are dealing with the gravity (which is a conservative force) we define for each conservative force a function which depends on the position only and also it's gradient gives us the conservative force back

\begin{gather} \int_{r_{1}}^{r_{2}} -\textbf{F}.\textbf{dr} =\Delta U \end{gather}

Since we are dealing with the y-axis only so **dr** become **dy** and **F**$=-m$**g**

So the integral above become the famous formula \begin{gather} \Delta U =mgh \end{gather}

Note: in your problem you define a reference which has $U=0$ , in this problem I define it as the ground where $h=0$ but when dealing with planets or electrostatics we take it as $U(\infty)=0$

Answer (score 1):

It is interesting that in your question you have part answered your queries.

You write *When we take a **body** up to some height, some work is done by us on the **body**, which is stored in the **body** and some work is done by gravity which is negative and so energy of **body** is lost. As the two works are equal and opposite they add up to zero.*
In these statements the system under consideration is only the **body** which has two external forces acting on it, gravitational attraction and your applied force.
The net work done on the system (**body**) by these two forces is zero and so the change in kinetic energy of the **body** is zero (work-energy theorem).

You then write *So, . . . . . we say potential energy of the system has increased?* which is a correct statement if the system is taken to be the body **and** the Earth with only one external force acting, your applied force, noting that the two gravitational forces, body on Earth, and Earth on body, are internal forces.
The work that you do on the system (Earth and body) changes the gravitational potential energy of the system (Earth and body).